# Why does re.VERBOSE cause regex to return empty?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s = '<a class="biz-name"><span>Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken</span></a>'
```

This returns the expected result:

```
regex = re.compile('''<a class="biz-name[\w\W]*?<span>(.*?)</span>''')
regex.findall()
['Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken']
```

however this returns empty:

```
regex = re.compile('''<a class="biz-name[\w\W]*?<span>(.*?)</span>''', re.VERBOSE)
regex.findall()
[]
```

The only difference is the `re.VERBOSE` flag.

Comment: Well, have you read the 4-line long documentation of that flag...?

Comment: yes but apparently didn't grok it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE):

> Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character class, or when preceded by an unescaped backslash, or within tokens like `*?`, `(?:` or `(?P<...>`.

The problem is that `'a class'` with `re.VERBOSE` is the same as `'aclass'`, which is not in your input. You'd need to escape the space (and use a raw string for general correctness):

```
re.compile(r'''<a\ class="biz-name[\w\W]*?<span>(.*?)</span>''', re.VERBOSE)
#      raw ^     ^ escape space or it doesn't count in VERBOSE mode
```